# How can I force a Word plugin to be re-enabled after being automatically disabled?

Tags: microsoft-word, plugins

I have been developing a plugin for MS Word (2007) and recently it was causing some crashes on exit and I guess Word automatically disabled it. I went into Word Options under COM Add-ins and checked the box to re-enable it, but when I click okay and then open Word again it's still shown as disabled. I tried looking for something in the registry for this but I wasn't able to find anything.

Is there some file or registry key that contains the enabled/disabled status of plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found that there are 2 different ways that plugins are disabled. "Hard" and "Soft". When a plugin is "Hard" disabled, such as what happens when it crashes Word, under Word Options->Add-Ins, instead of selecting COM Add-ins, you have to select "Disabled Items" and then select the Add-in and click "Enable". I don't know how I didn't see that option before, but there you go.